# I flashed 4.4 and now my Galaxy Nexus power button will not respond

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.4-kitkat, power-on

My Samsung Galaxy Nexus's power button is no longer responding. I flashed a ROM of 4.4 to it and now it no longer does anything. I made the mistake of taking the battery out and can no longer turn it back on. I've tried rebooting it through ADB, but it won't recognize the device because it is off. Has anyone run into this problem yet, or am I going to be stuck opening this thing up?

Comment: If you put on your charger.. Does it work？

Answer (score 0):

Attempt both and see if either work.

- Hold the power button for 10+ seconds
- Hold the power button and volume down button for 10+ seconds